# presentViewController gives Error

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

This is my first question here so it might not be in the best format.

In my app I want to show the next screen, this one is working fine when it is alone, so there should be no problem here. 
I am using the following code to make the transition

```
let dataViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Data")

            self.presentViewController(dataViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

on the second line `self.presentViewController` i get the error message:

> Cannot convert the expression's type '(AnyObject?, animated:
>   BooleanLiteralConvertible, completion: NilLiteralConvertible)' to type
>   'BooleanLiteralConvertible'

The only answer I found, with one having the same error, was that the function is `presentViewController` and not `presentedViewController`. I have to admit that I had exactly that problem. But after fixing this error in the code the error message did not disappear.
Could anyone show me the right direction to search or does someone even got an answer.

Comment: If the codebase is small, could you upload it to dropbox or somewhere?

Comment: Try changing the line to self.presentViewController(dataViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil) .. like put an ! after dataViewController

Comment: Thanks for the quick response i tried it with the forced unwrapping but the error is here to stay. And sorry but i can't upload the codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the expected type from `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` so use the following line when getting your view controller:

```
let dataViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Data") as UIViewController?
```

The `'as'` keyword informs the compiler of what is the real type you expect in return (aka. casting).

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` returns object of Type `AnyObject`. Since you didn't specify the type yourself `AnyObject` (equivalent to`id` in ObjC) will be used.

`presentViewController` expects a `UIViewController` instance and you give him `AnyObject` instead, hence the error

Comment: You should also test for nil before unwrapping the optional in `presentViewController`

Comment: @Paulw11 correct but in this case if storyboard is nil it better crash here as it must not be nil otherwise there is no point in continuing anyway